# Different behavior depends on exception in database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have web app based on JSP/Servlet. Database is MySQL. In web app there is `insertForm.jsp` that calls Servlet that calls `ins` method in java class.

```
imports ...

public class DBaddData extends HttpServlet {        

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
         some code
        ...
        //create an instanse of a class responsible for insert
       DBInsertRows dbir = new DBInsertRows();
        try {
        //call the inssert method
            dbir.ins(dbObj);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBaddData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        ...
        RequestDispatcher ...
    }

}
```

class who with `ins` method:

```
public class DBInsertRows {  
    public void ins(DBObjBaseStd dbObject) throws ClassNotFoundException
 {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;    
        String query = "INSERT INTO bla-bla-bla ...";    
        try {
            ...
           create con object
            ...    
            stmt = con.createStatement();    
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {    
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}
```

Insert process works fine, but! When I try to insert the same object (row) so that ID is already exists in a table I got an exception:
**MySQL text**

> ...Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry...

Apache Tomcat8 text

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for...

and this is totally fine. Not fine is that I do not have HTTP Status 500 hence I have no idea how get this exception and show on my `errorPage.jsp`
Another situation with `Delete` Idea is totally the same: user click delete button, jsp calls servlet that responsible for deletion that calls class with delete method. but if the user click delete without object chosen, I got exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

This is also fine. But now I also have `Throwable` exception or `error-code 500` hence the happy user see `errorPage.jsp` with correspond text.
Questions:

1. why there are different types of errors?
2. how can I pass the error text from `ins` method to my `errorPage.jsp`?

Comment: because sometimes you WANT to have different errors. e.g. a standard usage case is to check for duplicate usernames. if you do `select/check/insert`, there's a race condition with another process can insert behind your back. So you do an `insert` and check for duplicate key violation.

Comment: not sure I understand your question correctly. If the problem is that after you handle an SQL exception in your catch block there is no 500 status code, well, thats because you catch the exception. You'd have to set 500 status in the response manually in catch block by calling response.setStatus(500), and write any text you want by calling response.getWriter().print("....") (also pass an http response to the servlet).

Comment: There is no response object in the class that has `ins` method. It is just java class. **Servlet** calls the `ins` and error catches inside this method, not in **Servlet**. So what is better approach to send the information about the error to **Servlet**? My idea for now is to implement return value, but is it good idea?

Comment: My idea for now is to implement return value - bad idea. I found another solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if it is a good approach, but I added `throw` in a `catch` block. Now the code is:

```
 try {
            Class.forName(...driver...);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(... connection info...);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("class DBInsertRows caught SQLException -> "+sqlEx);      
        }
```

Now if user tried to duplicate information or, for example, the variable is longer than the field in the table he will get `errorPage.jsp` because `sqlEx` now is `Throwable` and `<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>`
Result in `errorPage.jsp`

> You caused a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class DBInsertRows caught SQLException -> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'TankName_UNIQUE' on the server.